# Struts Dojo Internationalization of values

Tags: java, struts2, dojo, internationalization

Is it possible to implement internationalization for Struts Dojo Tags?

For example:

I have this struts dojo submit tag:

```
<sx:submit cssClass="styled_button" targets="myDiv" value="close"/>
```

I want the [value="close"] to point to my properties file so that I can implement internationalization.

Is this possible with struts dojo?

Comment: As far As I know `dojo` plugin is deprecated from `struts2 ` use Struts-2 JQuery Plugin instead.

Comment: Oh I see.... I am merely handling maintenance for this project, and they don't want big changes like changing dojo to JQuery plugin.. So I have to deal with it this way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dojo` tag attribute `key` to get your locale value

```xml
<sx:submit cssClass = "styled_button" 
               name = "ss" 
            targets = "myDiv" 
                key = "yourKey" 
               name = "anyName" />
```

and `yourKey` will be property file you have mentioned in your `struts.xml`

Comment: I tried doing this but it will display **<s:text name="your_propertyKeyName" />** on the screen.

Comment: can this be possibly set using javascript/jQuery?

Comment: What you mean setting by javascript ? You have option to read from property files in dojo tag as mentioned in my answer

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Babel! This solved my problem! :D

Comment: Now I have another concern. I want to override the browser's language to my user's language.. For example, my browser's language is Japanese but my user's language is English, so the page should be displayed in English. I tried change the locale using request_locale but it did not solve the problem. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to ask another question with full details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89043/discussion-between-jaypax123-and-babel).

Comment: Sorry not able to access chat

Comment: new Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452884/struts-dojo-internationalization-how-to-override-browsers-language