# Struts-Dojo Internationalization (how to Override Browser's Language)

Tags: struts2, internationalization

I asked previously on how to implement Internationalization in struts-dojo ([Struts Dojo Internationalization of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447970/struts-dojo-internationalization-of-values/)). The answer solved my problem but I have another problem.

I want to override the browser's language to my user's language.
For exmaple, If my browser's language is **Japanese** but my user's language is **English**, the page should be displayed in **English**.

I tried overriding the browser's language by setting request_locale=en_US as parameter but the page language did not change.

Any solution to this problem would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you set `struts.locale`? Which properties files do you have for i18n?

Comment: Where do I set struts.locale? I have properties file for en and jp..

Comment: You can set it in struts.xml as a constant. You need a default properties file w/o language code, which will be the default. :)

Comment: I already set my properties file to the en properties file but still the page is displayed in Japanese.

Comment: *I already set my properties file to the en properties* - What do you mean?

Comment: I set the default properties file to the en properties file. (i.e. Resources_en.properties)

Comment: You mean in `struts.custom.i18n.resources`? Language code is most probably ignored there. Like I said use `struts.locale` and create a default properties file.